# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am using angular and I want to print all field from following json object

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Oasis Technology",
        "title": "Fill like getting water in destert",
        "email": "thorataniket777@gmail.com",
        "Phone": "7741091028  , 7774966527",
        "instagram": "https://instagram.com/",
        "linkedin": "https://www.linkedin.com/",
        "youtube": "https://youtube.com/"
    }
]
```

**Angular code**
.TS file

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public details:any
  url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/aboutus/?format=json"
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route :Router){
     this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(data=>{
       console.log(data)
      this.details=data
      
     });  
    }
```

.html file

```
<div class="p-5 text-center bg-light bg" style="height: 300px;" >
      <h1 class="mb-3"><span style="color: white;">Welcome to</span> <span style="color:gold;"> {{details[0].name}}</span></h1>
      <h4 class="mb-3"></h4>
      <h2 style="color: white;">{{details[0].title}}t</h2>
```

But i am getting error in browser console as

```
core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HeaderComponent_Template (header.component.html:7)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9575)
    at refreshView (core.js:9441)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10612)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9238)
    at refreshView (core.js:9491)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10612)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9238)
    at refreshView (core.js:9491)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:9555)
```

Comment: When you render the template `details` are undefined, and you start to call a http request to get data. After a moment, the request responses and you assign the response to `details`. Let's try `public details: any[] = [];` // init value

Comment: is the json file residing inside your app.

Answer (score 1):

This Api call
this.http.get(this.url).toPromise()
is an asynchronous task so when your app renders `HeaderComponent` this property `public details:any` is undefined and so details[0] in template will create Err Cannot read property '0' of undefined
You can fix this by using *ngIf like :

```
<div *ngIf="details && details.length"
 class="p-5 text-center 
 bg-light bg"
 style="height: 300px;">
 <h1 class="mb-3">
     <span style="color: white;">Welcome to</span>
     <span style="color:gold;">{{details[0].name}}</span>
 </h1>
 <h4 class="mb-3"></h4>
 <h2 style="color: white;">{{details[0].title}}t</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="p-5 text-center bg-light bg" style="height: 300px;" *ngIf="details.length>0">
          <h1 class="mb-3">
            <span style="color: white;">Welcome to</span> <span          
            style="color:gold;">{{details[0]?.name}}</span>
          </h1>
          <h4 class="mb-3"></h4>
          <h2 style="color: white;">{{details[0]?.title}}t</h2>
</div>
```